# Al Atributo line-height no se le aplica la transición

Tags: html, css

Estaba probando las transiciones y transformaciones de css y me encuentro con el siguiente problema, aqui estan algunas partes de mi html

el estilo:

```
    <style>
        p {
            transition:line-height 5s;
        }

        p:hover {
            line-height:2em;
        }
    </style>
```

el cuerpo:

```
<body>
        <p>
            Vivió en Rusia y Alemania la mayor parte de su vida y realizó importantes descubrimientos
            en áreas tan diversas como el cálculo o la teoría de grafos. También introdujo gran parte
            de la moderna terminología y notación matemática, particularmente para el área del análisis
            matemático, como por ejemplo la noción de función matemática. Asimismo se le conoce por sus nsfo
            trabajos en los campos de la mecánica, la óptica y la astronomía.
        </p>
</body>
```

el problema esque cuando yo paso el mouse pon el parrafo deveria lentamente agrandar el espacio entre las lineas pero lo hace instantaneamente ya lo probre en varios navegadores y usando -webkit-transition y tambien usando transition-propety y transition-duration .Me parece raro que no funcione por que las otras propiedras que e probado funcionan perfectamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner el `line-height` sin hover.
Así te funcionará:

```
     p {
     line-height:1em;
     transition:line-height 5s;

    }

    p:hover {
     line-height:2em;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ,me gustaría saber por que no funciona si poner line-height en p ya que el tiene un line-height por defecto pero bueno

Comment: Hasta donde sé, la transición necesita conocer de que valor a que valor debe de ir, y hay que indicarselos explicitamente, no sirve el valor por defecto del navegador o la herencia.